# Extending ViewController from Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I've this situation when I've decided to reuse and extend one of my `AViewController` which also extends `UITableViewController` with its view in `UIStoryboard A`.

So I've created a new protocol. `BViewController` which extends `AViewController` in the other `UIStroryboard`. I've added other `UITabelViewController` with class `BViewController`, Cell creation and all the other tableViews is on `AViewController` side. In the extended view I want to provide a new source of data for TableView.

I thought, since I'm extending existing VC with view. I don't have to recreate IBOutlets like tableView, cell etc. in a new view.
But at this point it seams that I should recreate a view in the other Storyboard? I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the view hierarchy for a scene in your storyboard is not inherited by another scene regardless of if you use the same subclass of `UIViewController` or not.  If you don't want to recreate the view hierarchy in your new scene, then you may need to put your view hierarchy in a .xib file and use `UINib` to do manual nib loading.

Comment: I'm not sure if this shouln't be next question but copy view hierarchy is more or less efficient than nib? Or is it just bad practice to do it?

Comment: It's not an efficiency concern from a runtime perspective.  But it is an issue when you have to make a change to your view and need to do it in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this solution.

```
    if let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AViewControllerIdentify") as? AViewController {
/// Runtime to set new sub viewcontroller class.
            object_setClass(destinationVC, BViewController.self)
            if let vc = destinationVC as? BViewController {
/// add you logic here.
}
```

}